# Problem generating an Access Token using Linkedin Two legged AuthenticationFlow

Tags: linkedin-api

When I try to generate an Access Token using the '**Two Legged Authorization flow**' I get the error below

**{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"This application is not allowed to create application tokens"}**

I understand that '**Two Legged Authorization flow**' is not enabled by default.
I would like to know how to enable it  so that I can use it in my application.

Thanks in advance

Mathew

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context

> If your application needs to access APIs that are not member specific,
> use the Client Credential Flow. Your application cannot access these
> APIs by default. Learn more about LinkedIn Developer Enterprise
> products to request permission to the Client Credential Flow.

You need to select an enterprise product, like the `Marketing Developer Platform`. Go to your app and request access to this product. Your app needs to be reviewed first so this may take some time.

Comment: did you have any luck getting 2-legged OAuth authentication work for LinkedIn? I have added all the products that I could for my app including the Marketing Developer Platform in the dashboard and I am still unable to get an application token.
I am following this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/skills/context